# Lighttpd QUERY_STRING escape properly

Tags: lighttpd, querystring

Problem is to escape query string in Lighttpd:

This is url:

```
domain/publisher/adframe-34.html?tag=xzzx&gg=yy&uu=121
```

and this is lighty rule:

```
adframe-([1-9][0-9]*)\.html\?(.*)" => "ad/frame.php?ad_unit_id=$1&addl=$2
```

What I am expecting is that `addl` contains : `tag=xzzx&gg=yy&uu=121` but I have this as response:

```
[ad_unit_id] => 34
[addl] => tag=xzzx
[gg] => yy
[uu] => 121
```

Is there some way to force Lighttpd to pass all in one param from query string, and to do that just with lighttp rule, without to parse `[REQUEST_URI]` from server?

Answer (score 1):

This rewrite rule:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
 "^.*/adframe-([1-9][0-9]*)\.html(\?(.*))?$" => "/ad/frame.php?ad_unit_id=$1&$3"
)
```

will rewrite request `/smth/here/adframe-3487.html?tag=zyx&gg=yy&uu=121` to `/ad/frame.php?ad_unit_id=3487&tag=zyx&gg=yy&uu=121`.

Will it resolve your problem?

Comment: I think OP wants `addl` contains every thing **escaped** from the url. Like `ad/frame.php?ad_unit_id= 34&addl=tag%3Dxzzx%26gg%3Dyy%26uu%3D121` You see? With all the query string encoded.